# Echo a true value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a value that is set to true, when I echo in blade it comes out as 1, how can I get it to echo true?

```
$test = true
{{ $test }} //1
```

Would it be best to set it as:

```
$test = 'true'
```

Or is there another way?

Comment: `echo $test ? 'true' : 'false';` Or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to echo `true` or `false` as string, do this:

```
{{ $test ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```